# Script to trigger email when the use % crosses 85%

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl

Output of one netbackup software commands reports below parameters. I want shell script to check the use% and if it > 85 then send email action stating which disk pool Name is greater than 85%.

```
server_hostname# netbackup command
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc01
Total Capacity (GB) : 2924.41
Free Space (GB)     : 2887.51
Use%                : 1
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc03
Total Capacity (GB) : 3919.52
Free Space (GB)     : 1314.14
Use%                : 66
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc02
Total Capacity (GB) : 3899.21
Free Space (GB)     : 3893.54
Use%                : 0
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc04
Total Capacity (GB) : 3901.59
Free Space (GB)     : 3591.03
Use%                : 7
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc07
Total Capacity (GB) : 86402.92
Free Space (GB)     : 26948.68
Use%                : 68
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc05
Total Capacity (GB) : 58928.13
Free Space (GB)     : 10401.51
Use%                : 82
Disk Pool Name      : dp_disk_abc06
Total Capacity (GB) : 86402.92
Free Space (GB)     : 13605.04
Use%                : 84
```

Any help to this is highly appreciated. Thank you..!

Comment: Not expert in scripting...tried using below logic...

#!/bin/sh
check () { grep -i Use% dpstatus.txt }
DP_THRESHOLD=85
if [ $(check) -ge $DP_THRESHOLD ]; then
mail -s Disk Pool down abc@gmail.com
fi

But encountering error and also I need the specific disk pool name to be stated in email which is greater than 85%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you're using is incomplete. You're found the in-use percentages, but the script needs extra steps to remember the disk pool name.

We often don't see flow charts, but for simple tasks, they're useful. The logic or method you can use to check the in-use percentage for the backup disk pools, and then send email goes like this:

[image: flow chart]

The rectangular blocks are things the script must do. The diamonds are decisions. The same method works for a Perl, Python, or Ruby script as well as bash. The blue block, for example, reads a line from a file. Here's how you can read lines from a file using bash:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo $line
    # the rest of the script goes here
done < "$filename"
```

The green diamonds decide if a line is interesting to the script. Other lines are ignored. If a line matches "Disk Pool Name", the script must remember the name from the end of the line.

The yellow diamonds decide if the script should send an email message. If a line matches "Use%", the script must check if the name it remembered is valid, and decide if the in-use percentage is greater than a threshold. If those decisions are true, the script sends email.

Here are some topics that may be useful when writing the script.

- [Read a file line-by-line in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453)
- [Pattern matching in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13150411)
- [Comparing numbers in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668556)